# Extract data from database to text file with PHP [Codeigniter]

Tags: php, codeigniter, header

I have this code

```
    $dateFile = "data.txt";
    $data = $this->Setting->Loop("data");

    foreach($data->result() as $dat){
        $dataString = "USERNAME| ".$dat->user." / DATA| ".$dat->values_text.".\n";
        file_put_contents($dateFile,$dataString);
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/text');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$dateFile);
    echo file_get_contents($dateFile);
```

which get data from table data and insert it into file called data.txt with this format

USERNAME| qwq / DATA| www.

My problem is that the code take just one record of data because the data stored in a single string, how can I make it get all records?

Edit #1
I found a solution and this is the new working code

```
    $dateFile = "data.txt";
    $data = $this->Setting->Loop("data");
    $dataContent = array();
    $i =  0;

    foreach($data->result() as $dat){
        $i++;
        $dataContent[$i] = "USERNAME| ".$dat->user." / DATA| ".$dat->values_text.".\n";
    }

    file_put_contents($dateFile,$dataContent);
    header('Content-Type: application/text');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$dateFile);
    echo file_get_contents($dateFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$filename = __dir__.'test.php';
$data = 'This is sample text';
fopen($filename, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$filename);
fwrite($handle, $data);
```

Hope this will help you